# Combine continue values from array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

My result should combine the consecutive tags,
if tags are the same then I want to combine those text into a single one.

So, from below input my output shoud be:

```
Speaker-2:Do you want the systems in English or en espanol
Speaker-1:Heinous Spaniel
Speaker-2:For English press one for Spanish press 2 in Espanol
Speaker-1:Choirs a horror Janeiro at e ends in the pro gun to sober Tuesday to enter but I will have email but if you a new window
Speaker-2:but I put one that's 1 or 2.0 press he only those
```

```js
 

   const note = [
    {
        text: 'do you want the systems in English or en espanol',
        tag: 2,
    },
    {
        text: 'heinous Spaniel',
        tag: 1,
    },
    {
        text: ' for English press one for Spanish press 2',
        tag: 2,
    },
    {
        text: ' in Espanol',
        tag: 2,
    },
    {
        text: ' choirs a horror Janeiro at e ends in the pro gun to sober Tuesday to enter',
        tag: 1,
    },
    {
        text: ' but I will have email but if you a new window',
        tag: 1,
    },
    {
        text: " but I put one that's 1 or 2.0 press he only those",
        tag: 2,
    },
];

const ip = note
    .map((e, i) => {
        const chanel = e.tag;
        let te = e.text.trim();
        const next = note[i - 1] ? note[i - 1].tag : 0;
        if (chanel === next) {
            te = `${note[i - 1].text.trim()} ${te}`;
            note[i - 1].text = te;
            note.splice(i, 1);
        }
        return {
            [`Speaker-${chanel}`]: te.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + te.slice(1),
        };
    })
    .filter(e => !!e);
let strimged = JSON.stringify(ip)
    .replace(/[{}"]/g, '')
    .split(',')
    .join('\n');
strimged = strimged.substring(1, strimged.length - 1);
console.log(strimged);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.reduce() is your answer.

```js
const note = [
    {
        text: 'do you want the systems in English or en espanol',
        tag: 2,
    },
    {
        text: 'heinous Spaniel',
        tag: 1,
    },
    {
        text: ' for English press one for Spanish press 2',
        tag: 2,
    },
    {
        text: ' in Espanol',
        tag: 2,
    },
    {
        text: ' choirs a horror Janeiro at e ends in the pro gun to sober Tuesday to enter',
        tag: 1,
    },
    {
        text: ' but I will have email but if you a new window',
        tag: 1,
    },
    {
        text: " but I put one that's 1 or 2.0 press he only those",
        tag: 2,
    },
];

 let previous = 0;

let result = note.reduce((total, item) => {

  if(item.tag === previous) {
    total += item.text;
  } else {
    total += `\nSpeaker-${item.tag}: ` + item.text;
    previous = item.tag;
  } 
  return total;
}, '');

console.log(result);
```